# Reading XML file from website from console application

Tags: c#, c#-4.0

What I want to accomplish is reading an xml file from a website (http://xml.buienradar.nl/). I have been reading about what to use, but I can't see the forest for the trees! Should I be using WebRequest, or XmlDocument, or XDocument, or XmlReader, or XmlTextReader, or? I read that XmlDocument and XDocument read the whole file into memory, and XmlReader doesn't. But is that a problem in this case? What if indeed the xml file is huge?

Can someone help me find a way?

Thanks!

Comment: use [XElement](https://www.dotnetperls.com/xelement)

Comment: `XmlReader` don't load whole XML into memory, but it will require more code than `XDocument`

Comment: `var doc = XDocument.Load("http://xml.buienradar.nl/");`

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov I typed this in just before your answer, and it works like a charm! Should I be concerned if the xml file is too long?

Comment: @GarthMarenghi It will load whole XML into memory first. Should consider it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To read huge XML without loading all of it into memory, you can use `XmlReader` class. But please note that this method requires more code than `XDocument` or even `XmlDocument` solution.

```
var h = WebRequest.CreateHttp("http://xml.buienradar.nl/");

using (var r = h.GetResponse())
using (var resp = r.GetResponseStream())    
using (var sr = new StreamReader(resp))    
using (var xr = new XmlTextReader(sr))       
{ 
    while (xr.Read())
    {
        // doing something with xr
        // for example print it's current node value
        Console.WriteLine(xr.Value);
    }
}
```

---

If you want to test for large XML file, you can try XML from   http://www.ins.cwi.nl/projects/xmark/Assets/standard.gz.

It is over 30 MB gzipped. With this method, XML processing don't require much memory, it even don't wait for whole file to finished downloading.

Test code:

```
var h = WebRequest.CreateHttp("http://www.ins.cwi.nl/projects/xmark/Assets/standard.gz");

using (var r = h.GetResponse())
using (var resp = r.GetResponseStream())
using (var decompressed = new GZipStream(resp, CompressionMode.Decompress))
using (var sr = new StreamReader(decompressed))
using (var xr = new XmlTextReader(sr))
{
    while (xr.Read())
    {
        // doing something with xr
        // for example print it's current node value
        Console.WriteLine(xr.Value);
    }
}
```

Comment: This is good to know. Since it is not a super critical application I opted to load the whole thing in memory.

Answer (score 1):

XmlTextReader provides a faster mechanism for reading xml.

```
string url="http://xml.buienradar.nl/";

XmlTextReader xml=new XmlTextReader(url);

while(xml.Read())
{
   Console.WriteLine(xml.Value);
}
```